# Command not found error on HISAT2

Tags: sequence-alignment, transcriptome, genomics

I have been attempting to map reads to a reference genome using HISAT2 using the Pertea, et al 2016 Nature Protocols paper. I am able to successfully generate an index (using the hisat2-build command), but when it comes to the actual mapping, I run into problems. The code I'm using (from the paper):

```
$hisat2 -p 8 --dta -x daphnia_tran -1 C2*R1*.fastq -2 C2*R2*.fastq -S C2paired.sam
```

And I get the error message:

```
./HISAT2_Basic_14.sh: line 26: -p: command not found
```

When I remove the -p argument, the error message is similar, but says "--dta: command not found"

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr: Remove the `$` from the command.

I imagine you're literally typing `$hisat2`, where you mean to instead type `hisat2`. The `$` is just meant to show the end of the command prompt. If you actually type `$hisat2`, you're not executing the hisat2 program, but whatever the `$hisat2` variable is set to. Since it's likely not set to anything, it's just ignored. For example:

```
ryan@maximus:~$ $hisat2 ls
bin              convertChromosomesChain.py  ...
```

Since there's no `$hisat2` variable, I'm actually just running `ls`. Likewise, your command is just reducing to `-p 8 --dta -x daphnia_tran -1 C2*R1*.fastq -2 C2*R2*.fastq -S C2paired.sam`, which is the source of the error.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thanks very much! The script seems to be running perfectly now.